# checking a date column for blanks and if it is less than sysdate then replace it with sysdate

Tags: oracle

I have a date column( schedule date) datatype as varchar
ex:
3/22/2017
4/28/2017
5/3/2017

1. I need to check for nulls and if found any make it as sysdate
2. All dates <=sysdate should be converted to sysdate

so the above 3 records should become sysdates and i just want to capture the month

3/22/2017 should become 'May'
4/28/2017 should become 'May'
5/3/2017 should become 'May'

Thanks!

Comment: Storing DATE (or TIMESTAMP) values in a `varchar` column is a really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agree it should be a DATE or TIMESTAMP column. TL;DR off topic - If you are forced use varchar for some reason then at least try to use ISO formatting in the text, YYYY-MM-DD so that you can sort the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of to_date(), to_char() functions and a case statement. Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE when schedule IS NULL THEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') 
       when (to_date(schedule, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < SYSDATE) THEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')
       else to_char(to_date(schedule, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MONTH')
  END AS SCHEDULE
FROM my_table;
```

The test:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE) VALUES ('3/22/2017');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE) VALUES ('4/28/2017');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE) VALUES ('5/3/2017');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE) VALUES (NULL);  -- test for null record
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (SCHEDULE) VALUES ('6/1/2019');  -- test for future record (current May 2019)

COMMIT;

SELECT SCHEDULE as ORIGINAL_VALUE, CASE 
   when schedule IS NULL THEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') 
   when (to_date(schedule, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < SYSDATE) THEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')
   else to_char(to_date(schedule, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MONTH')
  END as SCHEDULE_OUTPUT
 FROM my_table;

DROP TABLE MY_TABLE;
```

Results:

```
ORIGINAL_VALUE  SCHEDULE_OUTPUT
3/22/2017   MAY      
4/28/2017   MAY      
5/3/2017    MAY      
            MAY      
6/1/2019    JUNE
```

Comment: worked for me!...just tried the second part......thank you so much!!!! select CASE 
    WHEN to_date('4/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') <= sysdate then TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MON') else to_char(to_date('4/17/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MON') end as date_mod from dual